How to schedule jenkins job for alternate week?
Having 2 jenkins schedule file need to run each file alternate week means 1 file run current week and 2nd file should run on next week

I don't know Jenkins but can't you do something like If WeekNum() MOD 2 == 0 then ...?

When noting change to scheduling since 2012, you have a nice question (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472740/724039 on how to schedule a job)

But someone has done that!, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63972497/724039
